# Typo3 website migration, now backend login doesn't work

Tags: php, authentication, content-management-system, typo3, backend

I recently had to migrate a TYPO3 3.8.0 website from an old server onto a new one. Old server runs PHP 4.x new server 5.x. Migration went well, with only one image displaying differently.
The problem is that backend login doesn't work.

I use correct username and password, javascript and cookies are enabled. When I click log in, it takes a long time with the page loading icon, and then it goes to `ERROR 500 - Internal Server error`.

I've flushed caches, truncated old BE and FE user sessions (not that there are any FE users)... The user definitely exists. `/typo3temp` folder also definitely exists, with the right permissions.

I get these php errors in apache log:

**PHP Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in  /var/www/vhosts/2/104046/webspace/httpdocs/mydomain.com/typo3/t3lib/class.t3lib_‌​page.php on line 436 PHP Deprecated: Function call_user_method() is deprecated in /var/www/vhosts/2/104046/webspace/httpdocs/mydomain.com/typo3/t3lib/class.t3lib_‌​div.php on line 3413**

Could it be that the outdated TYPO3 version doesn't work with the new PHP version on new server?
Are these errors above related to my attempt to login? Are there any possible quick fixes?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the newer PHP version is very likely causing the problem. There is an [upgrade tutorial](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/doc_tut_upgrade_380_to_420/1.0.0/manual.html), which may be useful to you. After you have a running v4.x of TYPO3 on your server, you may want to use the 4.5LTS or the latest 6.1, but upgrading to those versions is less complicated if you already have a 4.x running. The jump from 3.8 to 4.2 is quite a big one, so good luck!